# How can I update the value of a pointer by pulling the value from an ini file?

Tags: c, linux, shell, jail

I am trying to make a few fixes and enhancements to [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit.8.html). The source is in CVS version control so I [cloned it to GitHub](https://github.com/MarcusEting/jailkit).

The way this is set up, you edit a user's home directory in `/etc/passwd` to be something like:

```
/home/jail/./home/username
```

Then the `getjaildir` function reads over that which is passed in as `oldhomedir` until it finds the first `/./` match right to left on the string and then will set `jaildir` to what is to the left of that and the `newhomedir` to everything to the right of that.

I want to be able to override `jaildir` with the value from a configuration file - but I suck at `c` and so I am having very difficult time even setting the variables manually.

Here is the [function](https://github.com/MarcusEting/jailkit/blob/master/src/jk_lib.c#L183):

```
/* if it returns 1 it will allocate new memory for jaildir and newhomedir
 * else it will return 0
 */
int getjaildir(const char *oldhomedir, char **jaildir, char **newhomedir) {
    int i=strlen(oldhomedir);
    /* we will not accept /./ as jail, so we continue looking while i > 4 (minimum then is /a/./ )
     * we start at the end so if there are multiple /path/./path2/./path3 the user will be jailed in the most minimized path
     */
    while (i > 4) {
/*      DEBUG_MSG("oldhomedir[%d]=%c\n",i,oldhomedir[i]);*/
        if (oldhomedir[i] == '/' && oldhomedir[i-1] == '.' && oldhomedir[i-2] == '/') {
            DEBUG_MSG("&oldhomedir[%d]=%s\n",i,&oldhomedir[i]);
            *jaildir = strndup(oldhomedir, i-2);
            *newhomedir = strdup(&oldhomedir[i]);
            return 1;
        }
        i--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

After many, many attempts at a more complex solution I tried a very simple, hard-coded variation:

```
int getjaildir(const char *oldhomedir, char **jaildir, char **newhomedir) {
    *jaildir = "/home/jail";
    *newhomedir = "/home/username";
    return 1;
}
```

This compiles fine on linux but when I run it I end up getting `Segmentation fault (11)`. I read up on pointers, addresses, dereferencing, variable types, string concatenation, etc. but unfortunately I'm used to loosely typed languages so this is pretty hard. What am I doing wrong?

**update**

Instead of setting the values in the `getjaildir` function I am attempting to set them in the mail loop.

At the top of the loop we have the variable definitions:

```
    char *jaildir=NULL, *newhome=NULL, *shell=NULL;
```

And here is where the function to set them is called:

```
if (!getjaildir(pw->pw_dir, &jaildir, &newhome)) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "abort, failed to read the jail and the home from %s for user %s (%d)",pw->pw_dir, pw->pw_name, getuid());
        exit(17);
}
```

Can I just do this immediately afterwards to overwrite the values?

```
jaildir="/home/jail";
newhome="/home/testuser";
```

When I try this it gives me:

```
*** glibc detected *** -su: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000004046ee ***
```

Comment: you can try gdb command to dbug the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call `getjaildir`?

When I tried it, it works, as it should.

```
int getjaildir(const char *oldhomedir, char **jaildir, char **newhomedir)
{
    *jaildir = "/home/jail";
    *newhomedir = "/home/username";
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ohome = "ohome";
    char *nhome = "nhome";
    char *jdir = "jdir";
    getjaildir(ohome, &jdir, &nhome);

    printf("%s:%s:%s\n", ohome, jdir, nhome);
}
```

Output:

```
ohome:/home/jail:/home/username
```

**update**

I looked at oyur link and now I think I know what the problem is. You are retrieving the password stucture with a call to `gepwnam`. However this function returns a static memory, which you should NOT overwerwrite. So either you have to copy the strcuture manually, before you start modifying it, or you provide your own memory to it. For details on how to this you can refer to http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam and look at `getpwnam_r`. Basically you allocate this memory beforehand and pass it to the function. You must make sure that enough memory is allocated as all the entries are put into this buffer you provided.
When you change your code accordingly it shouldn't crash.

Comment: It [gets called here](https://github.com/MarcusEting/jailkit/blob/master/src/jk_chrootsh.c#L366) and I can also print out the values but then when the program continues is when the segmentation fault occurs - so I was assuming that I was storing those strings as the wrong type, or not as a reference, or overflowing their allocated memory, or soemthing

Comment: This code is correct, and with the hardcoded version it should be save. So I think the problem is somewhere else. when you hardcode the values like in the above example, you shouldn't free them though. Where exactly does it segfault?

Comment: That makes sense. I'm going to try and figure out how to make it work. thank you!

Comment: Thanks I certainly will. Would be quicker with a code example ;)

Comment: For an examplecode you can look here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fgtpwnamr.htm. I would say to be on the save side, you can allocate 1024 bytes, which should be more then enough to keep all the elements from the pw entry.

Comment: ok maybe having a little trouble again - I see that `oldhomedir` is a password structure - but jaildir and newhomedir are not - so why is it a problem if I do what you did in the first block of code and return before they are assigned based on the password structure?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So the only option I can see for now is that you should use valgrind and check if it reports something. Your problem is most likely some uninitialized or stray pointer, but from just reading the code it's a bit hard to say.